# Get the count of nested ng-repeat in the outermost ng-repeat and update in dynamically according to ng-model value

Tags: html, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-filter, angularjs-ng-model

I have three nested ng-repeat to display the drives their corresponding folders and their corresponding files. A sample data is shown below

```
Drives=[  
   {  
      name:'C Drive',
      folders:[  
         {  
            name:'personal',
            files:[  
               {  
                  name:'a.txt'
               },
               {  
                  name:'b.txt'
               }
            ]
         }
      ]
   }
]
```

So I have three nested ng-repeat to display the drive name, its folders and the files in the folders.
How to get the total number of files in a drive and display it along the drive name.

Sample code

```
<div ng-repeat="drive in drives">
{{drive.name}} <I want the total count of files in a drive here>
    <div ng-repeat="folder in drive.folders">
    {{folder.name}} {{filteredfiles.length}}
        <div ng-repeat="file in filteredfiles=(folder.files | filter 
        {name:search})">
        {{file.name}}
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<input type="text" ng-model="search"/>
```

Note that I have a search filter so the number of files in a drive should get updated dynamically according to the filter value applied to denote the number of files with the same name as the search value in a particular drive.

How to incrementally count the number of files in a drive and apply two way binding such that the count gets updated according to the search value ?

For Angular version 1.6

Comment: What version of angular?

Comment: For Angular version 1.3

Comment: Are you stuck with angular 1.3? This could be handled differently with a higher version (1.5 or above). 

You'd have to post the relevant controller layout though to be able to answer the question fully

Comment: Sorry. Its 1.6.4 version and the controller has just the JSON object which is to be displayed

Comment: So, you are using components then, correct?

Comment: Yes Components...

Comment: Then what you want is data binding through components. Here's a little tutorial...   https://toddmotto.com/one-way-data-binding-in-angular-1-5/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modify `filteredfiles` so that they are contained in a controller object that you can iterate to get total length of all the arrays. Use index of drive for first level keys and folder index for next level.

Then use a controller function that uses  `Array#reduce` ( or a `for in` loop)  to iterate all the various object keys to sum all the array lengths

**View:**

```
 <div ng-repeat="drive in drives">

    <strong>{{drive.name}}</strong>  -- File count:{{filteredFileCount($index)}}

    <div ng-repeat="folder in drive.folders" ng-init="driveIndex = $parent.$index">
     {{folder.name}} has {{filteredfiles[driveIndex][$index].length}} files
     <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="file in filteredfiles[driveIndex][$index]=(folder.files | filter:{name:search} ) ">
        {{file.name}}
      </li>
     </ul>

    </div>
  </div>
```

**Controller:** (or put business logic in service)

```
  // object to hold arrays filtered in view
  $scope.filteredfiles = {};

  $scope.filteredFileCount = function(driveIndex) {

    let driveObj = $scope.filteredfiles[driveIndex] || {};

    return  Object.keys(driveObj).reduce((a, c) => {
      return a + (Array.isArray(driveObj[c]) ? driveObj[c].length : 0);
    }, 0);

  }
```

<kbd>**[DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/1XegYU4jlac73zKzGPxW?p=preview)**</kbd>

Comment: Worked perfectly ..Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There's two ways to handle this. If using components and the components are appropriately nested, as they should be, you can simply hand down a variable in your child component definition as such:

```
.component('ComponentName', {
    bindings: {
          myVariable: '=' //Look up the appropriate sigil for the binding behavior you want
        }, 
`//....rest of component def here

    })
```

Then you would simply hand it down through your directive that you've made in your router (or when you instantiate the component)

```
<my-directive my-variable="$ctrl.myVariable"></my-directive>
```

Example: https://toddmotto.com/one-way-data-binding-in-angular-1-5/

Alternatively, you would just make a service and have it be a dependency in both controllers and set the value there through getters/setters, since services are singleton and can maintain the value between controllers.